Nswag CSharp Client generator marking strings as Required
I have a .Net 8.0 WebAPI project which Im using NSwag to produce a c# SDK APIClient class so that I can interact with it from another project.
NSwag is marking all strings with this attribute
 [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("longUrl", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string LongUrl{ get; set; }

It does this for all strings.  The issue I have is that when I call the client and it tries to deserialise the json to an object it fails when the string is not provided.
I'm not sure what Im supposed to do here?  If I  manually change
Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull 
to Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default 

then it works but I dont want to have to manually update the whole file after every build.
Do I need to mark up my DTO's with a nullable string
eg:
string? LongUrl { get; set; }

Or is there a way of getting Nswag to always use Default?

Have you found a solution for this?

From .NET 6 the non-nullable property must be required. As you said you can use ? or set default value to allow nullable. If you want to globally achieve the requirement, just open the project file and remove <Nullable>enable</Nullable>.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <!--<Nullable>enable</Nullable>-->
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>


Hi - i have tried this but unfortunately it doeesnt fix the issue with the Nswag generation

Hi @glenho123, what do you mean for Nswag generation? From your original post, What you want is to make the string type data nullable, right?
